# ¿Hay una forma más sencilla de separar caracteres en R? (ver ejemplo)

Tags: string, r

Supongamos que tengo una cadena conformada por 10 caracteres y me interesan únicamente los primeros tres, utilizando los primeros dos para una variable y el tercero para otra.

Así, por ejemplo:

```
string <- "1002034908"
string1_3 <- substr(string, 1,3)
string1_2 <- substr(string1_3, 1,2)
string3 <- substr(string1_3, 3,3)

string1_2    #10
string3      #0
```

La pregunta es muy sencilla: ¿Existe una forma más rápida de alcanzar este mismo resultado?

Gracias de antemano por cualquier orientación

Comment: Cuando mencionas rapidez, hablas de performance o de escribir menos código?

Comment: No lo había pensado de esa forma. En particular, me interesa escribir menos código, pero si además tenemos ganancia en desempeño, sería fabuloso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mucho más sencillo, pero algo más cómodo de escribir sobre todo si son múltiples los recortes a realizar, y siempre que te sirva recibir todo en una única variable tipo lista, tienes la opción de usar [`substring()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html) que permite configurar los parámetros `start` y `end` como vectores, por lo que podrías estar haciendo esto:

```
string <- "1002034908"
lista <- substring(string, c(1,3),c(2,3))
lista[1] # pos 1 - 2  = 10 
lista[2] # pos 3 - 3  = 0
```

Comment: En realidad es para crear variables en un data.frame. En una encuesta, los idenfiticadores de algunas variables tienen 10 dígitos, de los cuales son los 3 primeros los que ocupo para crear a su vez otras dos variables. Si no hay forma más rápida de hacerlo, entonces creo que voy por buen camino. Saludos y muchas gracias, como siempre.